# App crashes when recorder is supposed to stop

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an app uploaded on google play. [This is the link.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad)

It hasn't been tested on many devices yet so errors are pretty common. A user messaged me today saying that the app crashes if the togglebutton is turned ON and the button is only pressed, not held.

This is the logcat file that he sent me:

```
E/MessageQueue-JNI(31135): java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
E/MessageQueue-JNI(31135): at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(31135): at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.MainActivity.stopRecording(MainActivity.java:183)
```

Quote:

> App doesn't always crash. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. It only happens when the togglebutton is ON. If I touch and hold the button it works fine but if I only touch it for a moment it crashes. I'm using Xperia S 4.1.2

I tried this on my phone, I only touched the button instead of holding it and it worked perfectly fine, I don't know why this is happening on his phone.

This is the code for onTouchListener:

```
recBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    startRecording();
                }
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    stopRecording();
                    nameAlert();
                }
            return true;
            }
        });
```

And the logcat says the problem occurs when stopRecording is called, so here is the stopRecording method:

```
public void stopRecording() {
    final ImageButton recBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.id.recButton);
    final ToggleButton tBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tBtn1);
    if (null != recorder) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release(); 
        recorder = null;

        recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn);
        stopTimer();
        tBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that the problem is that he only touches the button for a moment, so before startRecording is completely called, the stopRecoring is already called so it crashes because startRecording wasn't even completely intiated yet. If that's the case, how can I fix it? If it isn't the case, what's wrong then? And why would an error like this appear on another phone but not mine?

Comment: To be clear: the idea here is that the application records for just however long the button is held down?

Comment: @chrylis Yes, exactly. You can download the app and see for yourself how exactly it's supposed to work but yes, it works exactly as you described if the togglebutton is on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to documentation, this is the normal behavior:

> `public void stop ()`
>
> Added in API level 1 Stops recording. Call this after start(). Once
>   recording is stopped, you will have to configure it again as if it has
>   just been constructed. **Note that a RuntimeException is intentionally
>   thrown to the application, if no valid audio/video data has been
>   received when stop() is called**. This happens if stop() is called
>   immediately after start(). The failure lets the application take
>   action accordingly to clean up the output file (delete the output
>   file, for instance), since the output file is not properly constructed
>   when this happens.

So you can just add a try catch to your `stop` call

```
if (null != recorder) {
   try{     
      recorder.stop();
   }catch(RuntimeException ex){
   //Ignore
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Seriously? It intentionally throws a bare `RuntimeException`?

Comment: Yep, if the MediaRecorder hasn't received any data. If the user is touching the button for only a moment, then MediaRecording, starts recording but doesn't get any input (since it stops immediately), hence the `RuntimeException`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this, send the updated apk to this user and see if it works. I'll let you know and accept your answer if it works :)

Comment: It took a while to get a response but seems like the problem is solved. Instead of crashing, the app now shows a toast. Thank you :)

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: I don't know a better solution, sorry.